# What is an alternative to running SQL query in code-first migration script?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Goal is to add data to DB table.
I can generate an empty migrations script and add this in Up() method.

```
  migrationBuilder.Sql($"INSERT INTO [User].[ExtraUser](Id,Name,Description)" +
                    "Values('123','Extra1', 'description')"
```

This works but there are cases where I have to add data in lots of columns and writing insert script seems rather uncomfortable. Is there a better alternative to this?

Comment: if your talking about SQL server, you could try SSIS SQL Server Integration Services, it's an ETL thing (extract , transform, load)

Comment: If you prefer C#, you can use [`.HasData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding), but either way you're going to either have to write a lot of SQL or a lot of C#.  You should consider generating the script (either c# or SQL) somehow and copying it into the migration.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily "write" all the sql statements - but at the end of the day any procedure to load data into sql server is fair game as an alternative.